# Converting MySQL 5.6.10 - 32 bit to 64 bit version

Tags: 64-bit, mysql

I am currently using MySQL DB  Version 5.6.10  for 32 bit running in 64 bit Window OS.I want to change it to 64 bit without taking any dump..Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Both are different architecture you have to take a dump and reinstall 64 bit mysql.

Comment: I think that it's not possible to do this without reinstall, but search in google for "migrate mysql 32 64 bit"

Comment: Take backup all your databaes, uninstall mysql x32, go to c:\program files (x86)\ delete folder mysql, install mysql x64 and restore your databases!